# I try to dockerizing my node server but I got an Error: Cannot find module './router/Seller'

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Here is my server.js file. I try to dockerizing my node server but I got an Error: Cannot find module './router/Seller'. How can I solve this problem?

```
const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors")

const app = express();

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dotenv = require("dotenv")

const port = 5000;

const SellerRouter = require('./router/Seller'); 

dotenv.config(); 

mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://name:pass@cluster0.mcg5e.mongodb.net/Databasename?retryWrites=true&w=majority`).then(()=>console.log("DB connected successfully")).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
})

app.use(cors()); 

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/seller" , SellerRouter)

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`SERVER IS RUNNING at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16 
WORKDIR /Backend
ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
COPY . .
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]


ENV MONGO_URL = mongodb+srv://name:Your password@cluster0.mcg5e.mongodb.net/Databasename?retryWrites=true&w=majority
ENV JWT_SEC = Your password
ENV PASS_SEC = Yourr password
```

Here is my result which means error

```
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Backend/index.js:9:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Backend/index.js' ]
}
PS C:\Users\khadk\OneDrive\Desktop\dd>
```

Comment: How are you launching the container?  If you're trying to replace the image content using volume mounts that could result in this problem.

Comment: (Note that anyone who can access your Docker image can `docker inspect` it to see the environment variables; that is not the right place to specify cloud database host names or secrets like the JWT signing key.)

Comment: I'm new to docker so I don't know that much. I run this code in terminal :  docker build -f Dockerfile -t meco/server .             docker run -it -p 5000:5000 meco/server

Comment: If you `docker run --rm meco/server ls -l ./router`, is the `Seller.js` file there?  (It looks like you're on a Windows host but a Linux container; did it potentially lose its capitalization?)  You can also `docker run --rm -it meco/server sh` to get an interactive shell to explore the built image further.